# How to convert json to associative array in JSP

Tags: json, jsp, gson

I'm trying to make a dynamic jsp page based on the json.

For example, if my json is look like this:

```
{
    'page1':'true',
    'page2':'true',
    'page3':'false'
}
```

In php, I could get my associative array easily by one line:

```
$data = json_decode($json_str);
```

Then I could access whichever that I wanted at the place I needed, (i.e)

```
If($data['page1'] == 'true') 
    echo #page link#;
```

But in jsp, it doesn't goes so easily because it don't have much documents like php. I find the `gson` but still not sure. how to use it to achieve it.

Please give me some example that I could turn json to associative array, then get and access it in jsp.

Comment: Look like this is a hard problem and Java9 didn't have plan to solve this out by adding json api, so I'll dodge this problem by using other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java `Map` is an associative array. You can ask Gson to deserialize your json input with this:

```
Map<String,String> map = new Gson().fromJson(inputJson, new TypeToken<Map<String,String>>() {}.getType());
```

Example code:

```
package net.sargue.gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

public class SO36859440 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputJson = "{\n" +
            "    'page1':'true',\n" +
            "    'page2':'true',\n" +
            "    'page3':'false'\n" +
            "}";

    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
    Map<String,String> map = new Gson().fromJson(inputJson, type);

    System.out.println(map.get("page2"));
    System.out.println(map.get("page3"));
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
true
false
```

Then, your question is about converting it in JSP. Well, best practices for JSP advice you to move this kind of processing to a Servlet that acts as a controller and passes attributes to the JSP in order to build the view. You can put code directly on the JSP using `<% ... %>` but I highly discourage you to do so. But that's an entirely different question.